# Why is var_dump($_POST) not showing all my variables?

Tags: php, html, post

I have a form with over 350 name="somename" attached to HTML input elements.  When I run a var_dump($_POST) only 150 of them show up, what's going on?

Comment: you may have duplicate names or unchecked checkboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that in the html, you are using

```
<input name="name[]" value=""/>
```

instead of

```
<input name="name" value=""/>
```

php will overwrite $_POST['name'] with each new name field if they don't have the brackets in the name attribute.

Comment: This wasn't the issue but you made me realize I was missing blank values on some boxes.  Its all good now. Thanks.

Comment: That is value="" was not on some items - the ones not showing up in var_dump